# What is a time complexity for sets and maps created with a factory methods Set.of() and Map.of()?

Tags: java, collections, java-9

In Java, when I create a `set` with `Set.of()` or a `map` with `Map.of()` what is the time complexity of the `contains` and `get` operations? Is it O(1)?

Comment: They are unmodifiable, you cannot `add` to a `Set.of()` returned `Set`.  [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable)

Comment: ok, what about `get`?

Comment: using forEach() method.

Comment: I ask about time complexity. If there is 10000 items in the Map, depending on the implementation, it can be O(1) or O(logN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Set.of` and `Map.of` APIs return instances of JDK-private implementations. The performance of these implementations is not guaranteed by the specification. However, the APIs do return specific implementations about which performance statements can be made. Thus, the question is reasonable and is distinct from a (hypothetical) question such as "What is the performance of `Map.get`?" which is a poor question because there are many different `Map` implementations.

In any case, the implementations behind `Set.of` (for size greater than two) and `Map.of` (for size greater than one) use a simple open addressed hashing scheme with linear probing for collision resolution. The `Set.contains` and `Map.get` operations are O(1) if the elements' (keys') hashes are reasonably well distributed.