# Is the Access Time Complexity of a Map Created by Map.ofEntries() the Same as HashMap which is o(1)?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, immutability, java-9

I wanted to create an **immutable hashMap** inline using the new factory method `Map.ofEntries()` in Java 9, for example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(1, "One"),
    Map.entry(2, "Two"),
    Map.entry(3, "Three"));
```

Then to my surprise, I found I could not create an immutable hashMap the same way! For example, the following code would not work.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = HashMap.ofEntries( //not work
    Map.entry(1, "One"),
    Map.entry(2, "Two"),
    Map.entry(3, "Three"));
```

Then when I want to check what type of map is returned by the factory method, I found the following [note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable):

> Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances.

So my question is, is the access time complexity of an immutable map the same as a hashMap which is o(1)? If not, how to create a map that is both immutable and access o(1) at the same time? It would be best if it can be created inline.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043254/how-to-get-a-immutable-collection-from-java-hashmap

Comment: You expect that `.ofEntries` would return an instance of a concrete class `HashMap` but it returns a (different) implementation of interface `Map`. Sure it won't work.

Comment: Why is it so important to create a HashMap?  What’s wrong with a plain Map?

Comment: One approach for really immutable maps (and not only *unmodifiable* maps) is (ignoring Guava or other third-party libraries): `Map<K, V> immutableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(realMap));`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636750/3182664

Comment: @VGR The question in your comment, as it is currently phrased, does not make sense, *unless* you already know the answer or what the question is aiming at. But I think the last paragraph from the question makes clear that the point is not to "know" that it **is** a `HashMap`, but only to be sure that the returned map has the same complexity characteristics as a `HashMap` - namely, mainly, O(1) for `get`.

Comment: @Marco13 or `Map<K, V> immutableMap = Map.copyOf(realMap);` And the time complexity [has been discussed only one month before this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57557125/2711488)…

Comment: @Holger That's right. Although the `LinkedHashMap` approach works for Java `<9`, **and** has the guarantees about the complexity, for that matter...

Comment: @Marco13 well, this is a Java 9 question and I wouldn’t worry about the time complexity, as I suppose, if a JRE vendor decides to use a different implementation, they do it for a good reason.

Comment: @Holger To be honest: The `of`-methods only accept so few parameters that even returning a "list-based map" (with O(n) for `get`) would rarely make a difference in practice - but there's nothing wrong with asking, of course.

Comment: @Marco13 there’s also the varargs method `Map.ofEntries(…)` and since Java 10, you can use `Map.copyOf(existingMap)` which has no size limit. But indeed, having a fixed size and unspecified implementations implies that the time complexity may become pointless, as it tells, how an implementation scales while constant maps do not need to scale. E.g. `Set.of("foo", "bar")` will return a special implementation which had an `O(n)` lookup time complexity, if it wasn’t limited to at most two elements anyway…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mutability or immutability are not directly related to the complexity of the access operation in a `Map`. For instance, a `HashMap` will always be `O(1)` for the `get()` operation, whereas a `TreeMap` will be `O(log n)`. It's the *implementing* class of the `Map` interface that determines the complexity of the operations.

Besides it's always been possible to create unmodifiable maps, because we can make any `Map` of any concrete type immutable after we put items on it, like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> immutableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mutableMap);
```

To be clear, `HashMap.ofEntries()` won't work because the `ofEntries()` method is static and defined in the `Map` interface, not in any of its implementing classes.

And you should not worry about being unable to declare the type of a map as `HashMap` or some other concrete class, anyway the best practice is to declare the map as being of a `Map` interface.

Also, if you were using a version older than Java 9 and don't mind using an external library, you can use [`ImmutableMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) from Guava:

```
Map<Integer, String> immutableMap = ImmutableMap.of(key1, val1, key2, val2);
```

Perhaps reading [this article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-9-immutable-collections-example/) will clarify things a bit more.

Comment: Just the usual reminder: `immutableMap` is itself immutable, but can be altered, when someone alters `mutableMap`.

Comment: Is it possible to know what is the class type of the implementing object returned by the factory method `Map.ofEntries()`? If so, I can have an idea of its time complexity.

Comment: @FrankMi Just look into the implementation. Your IDE should allow you to do so. That method `AbstractImmutableMap` defined in `java.util.ImmutableCollections`

Comment: Sure, just print the result of `.getClass()` on the object. But as it says in the documentation, it's an _implementation detail_ and it can change at any moment. That's why we should assign the result of `Map.ofEntries()` to a `Map` interface, not a concrete implementation class.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez it returns `class java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN` which is beyond my knowledge... Do you how to get its complexity? But I agree with you and I will not depend on its returning type.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that it's `O(1)` for the `get()` operation, any decent implementation of a non-sorted map should be `O(1)`. If it weren't, it'd say so in the documentation.

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean my IDE should allow me to do?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thank you. It helps me a lot!

Comment: @FrankMi An IDE allows you to jump into the implementation of methods/classes, usally by left click why you hold CTRL key. There you then can see the implementation.

Comment: What Tom pointed out in the first comment is also detailed (with an example) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636750/3182664

Comment: @Holger I didn't mention any "advantages" in my answer, it's just an alternative, in case someone is wondering how to do this pre-Java 9

Comment: @Óscar López At least in Java 11, looking at the code, Map.ofEntries is O(n).